# Why can I derive from Fact, whereas Trait is sealed?

Tags: c#, inheritance, xunit

I was thinking about creating an attribute which derives from `Xunit.Trait` with which I can attribute my facts. The idea is that the name of the type provided is set as a trait value. Something along these lines:

```
[Tests(typeof(Foo.Bar))] // would be equivalent to [Trait("Type", "Foo.Bar"]
[Fact]
public void TestsFooBarConstructor()
{
  var x = new Foo.Bar();
  // ...
}
```

Knowing that `Xunit.Fact` attribute can be further specialized, I expected it to be the same with `Trait` attribute and created the following attribute class

```
public class TestsAttribute : TraitAttribute
{
  public TestsAttribute(Type t)
    : base("Type", t.FullName)
  {
  }
}
```

until I found out that `Trait` is sealed. Is there a reason for this design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By being able to determine the intent of the code simply by looking at the test rather than having to run it means that the user's can understand the test intent earlier before a compiler is invoked.

Many new attributes are sealed (rather than using inheritance) because they wanted to be able to support test discovery from the environment with automation tools (**where the code may not even compile**, so it's done with an abstract syntax tree) like Resharper, CodeRush, Roslyn etc ...

see more details by xunit contributors [here](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/394)

Comment: The tools could look for the attribute type or one that is derived from it. Feasible, but an performance issue on the tool side maybe?

Comment: @David They'd be able to see that `TestsAttribute` is derived from `TraitsAttribute`, but without running it, they'd not be able to see the arguments you're passing to the base class constructor.